# button onClick doesn't work when disabled=True is initialized (Reactjs)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a button which I initialize as disabled that I enable when another event happens.
But when I click on it the onClick function isn't called.

```
<div className='button-parent'>
    <button id="saveButton" type="button" onClick={updateBill} disabled={true} className="button">Save</button>
</div>
```

I have the opacity change when it's enabled, so I'm sure it's enabled when I try to press it and it doesn't work.

I'm sure the function is fine as when I add the onClick to the parent element, it works fine.

Comment: How are you re-enabling the button? `disabled` is set to a perpetual `true`

Comment: The error is not here. This works for me: https://wfzg9.csb.app/

Comment: @Phix you're right, that was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make something like this :

```
const [enable, setEnable] = useState(true);

<button id="saveButton" type="button" disabled={enable} className="button">Save</button>
```

You can call the function to update the state and you can use the following to update state :

```
setEnable(!enable).
```

This will toggle the state and enable or disable the button using the previous state.

Answer (score 1):

Use a state to manage the disabled condition instead of hardcoding it to true.

```
const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState(true)

<button id="saveButton" type="button" onClick={updateBill} disabled={isDisabled} className="button">Save</button>
```

When your other event happens and you want to enable it just

```
setIsDisabled(false)
```