# onClick function is not called after I have enabled the button in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a `textarea` and a `button`. The button is disabled by default and when the user starts typing, I enable the button to be clicked. But the problem is that, the `onClick` function is not called while already `disabled = false` was set.

I've seen this: [button onClick doesn't work when disabled=True is initialized (Reactjs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69380725/button-onclick-doesnt-work-when-disabled-true-is-initialized-reactjs)
Seems to be a good idea, but after I setState with the new value, my component is re-rendering, and I don't really want that.

```
const refText = useRef(null);
const refBtn = useRef(null);

function handleBtnStatus(e) {
    let text = e.target.value;
    if(text.replace(/\s/g, "").length > 0) {
        refBtn.current.disabled = false;
    }
    else {
        refBtn.current.disabled = true;
    }
}

function postThis() {
    console.log("You posted! Text:", refText.current.value);

    // disable again
    refBtn.current.disabled = true;

    // delete previous text wrote
    refText.current.value = "";
}

return (
    <>
        {isLogged && (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="content">
                    <div className="utool-item-text">
                        <textarea name="textArea" placeholder="Write something.." ref={refText} onChange={(e) => handleBtnStatus(e)}></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div className="utool-item-post">
                        <button className="ust-btn-post" ref={refBtn} disabled={true} onClick={postThis}>Da Tweet</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="posts-section">
                    <div className="list-posts">
                        {posts.map((p) => {
                            return (p.hidden === false ? (
                                <div className="post" key={p.id}>
                                    <div className="post-text">
                                        <span>{p.text}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            ) : (''))
                        })}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )}
    </>
)
```

Any help?

Comment: You **must** not maniûlate DOM directly when using React. So you have to store your textarea value in a state, and enable/disable the button depending on the state value, directly in JSX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use state instead of refs, re-rendering is ok for your case

Simplified example:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const SimpleExample = () => {
  const [textAreaValue, setTextAreaValue] = useState('');

  return (
    <>
      <button disabled={!textAreaValue} onClick={() => console.log('onClick handler')}>
        click me
      </button>
      <textarea value={textAreaValue} onChange={(e) => setTextAreaValue(e.target.value)} />
    </>
  );
};
```

And I would recommend checking this [Use state or refs in React.js form components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29503213/use-state-or-refs-in-react-js-form-components)

Comment: Alright, I will just use like that! Thank you!